# Can i keep a transaction alive while killing corrensponding connection?

Tags: sql-server, transactions

in sql server, if i begin a transaction, and close that application, the transaction will be roll back automatically.

i wonder if there 's any way to keep alive the transaction when the app is down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No I don't think so. I think this design is wrong. You should be using a [Compensation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compensating_transaction) approach, not a Transaction approach.

A transaction can lock resources (depending on the isolation strategy). You probably don't want this.

Have a read of this [IBM article](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/cjta_wsbascope.html).

Answer (score 0):

When you're committing to the DB you're basically saying that the data to be written is correct and processed by the application.
Data will be written only if transaction is closed, and this contract means, that the DB won't contain invalid/corrupted information.
So, no. You cannot keep-alive transactions after you close the connection.